# More economical times to fly from New York to Paris

Tags: air-travel, budget

What are the least expensive times to fly round trip from New York to Paris?

In terms of times of year: what is off season when an airline ticket would be cheaper?

And in terms of length of trip: How long a stay reduces the price of the airline ticket and over what days of the week?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Why not just set up an alert to notify why about price changes?

Comment: @Karlson, I'm looking to find a better time to plan a trip now. Not much of a power traveler, so perhaps your suggestion makes sense in that context, and I'm not getting it?

Comment: When you go to site like Travelocity you can save an itinerary and create an email alert for price changes.

Comment: It's really tricky. The price changes a lot. It can go up and down as you get nearer/closer the day. Tuesday through Thursday are - generally - cheaper than Friday through Monday. If you just want "a cool european holiday" consider Milan (which is much better anyway! :) ) rather than Paris, it's sometimes (not always) cheaper to fly.  Same for Amsterdam.

Answer (score 3):

You can do wide [year long searches with Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.com/transport/flights/nyca/pari/cheap-flights-from-new-york-to-paris.html?rtn=1).

Cheaper tickets can be found by using [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) to search multiple airports from one place to another, you can't book using ITA Matrix but it can be used to find cheap deals.

You can set up Flight Price Alerts using [Kayak](http://www.kayak.com/).

Prices can vary upon which airline, airport and how many people have booked and which fare class is available. Obviously major holidays and major school holidays are the more expensive due to more people traveling.

Answer (score 1):

There're plenty of variables that defines the price of a ticket. In general it comes to this:

1. Time in advance you purchased the ticket (the longer [usually)] the better)
2. Stay in destination
3. Seasonality

To answer your question regarding length of trip (item 2) look at the [Saturday night Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturday-night_stay). This distinguish business from pleasure. So you'll know when to return ;-)